# Tomcat Server Installation

Tags: apache, environment-variables

I was installing Tomcat server on my system (Windows XP). It was required to set three environment variables namely `path`,`JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH`. But for Windows 8 , another environment variable `CATALINA_HOME` was required to be set.

Why this difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Tomcat server 4.x and above consists of 3 main parts: Catalina (a servlet container), Coyote (an HTTP connector) and Jasper (a JSP engine). 
AFAIK, the installation of Tomcat (at least version 6, 7, 8), **regardless** of windows OS (XP, 7, 8), consists of the following steps:

- setting *JAVA_HOME* env. variable
- setting *CATALINA_HOME* env. variable (This represents the root of your Tomcat installation i.e shows where servlet container is)
- updating  *PATH* env. variable with %PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin

My assamtion that you used to install Tomcat incorrectly using **CLASSPATH** env. variable. Info from the oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html):

---

> The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the
>   JDK tools, where to look for **user** classes. (Classes that are part
>   of the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through
>   other means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions
>   directory.) **Setting the CLASSPATH can be tricky and should be
>   performed with care**

Tomcat is definitely **not** coupled with **user** classes, and one should not use that variable for its installation.

Comment: @IIya Thanks for the detailed explanation. I should have used **CATALINA_HOME** rather **CLASSPATH** to install tomcat. But still Tomcat was installed successfully, without setting **CATALINA_HOME**. Any idea ,how was that possible ?

Comment: @JOHN you are welcome. The question is are you running tomcat from IDE or via startup.bat / startup.sh ? The point is that if you are running it from ide you do not need to set variables at all (at least in eclipse case). However, if you are running it via bat / sh file Path var must incude info where Tomcat is. Otherwise it deffinitelly will not work

Comment: @IIya Yes, I got it. Actually i was running it through startup.bat . But i already had Netbeans IDE installed on my system, which must have automatically set the required system variables for **Tomcat**.